# detecting mobile browser without user agent sniffing

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, media-queries

Which approach is more reliable to detect a mobile browser?

- UA sniffing
- Jquery's `width()`

As I understand UA sniffing is not very reliable.

I need to change the HTML for a page according to the width of the mobile device viewing the page. I can't do that with media queries alone.

Comment: Are you changing the way certain elements look because the screen is narrow?  If so, use media queries.  If you're changing the way an element behaves (eg. mobile doesn't have a mouse, so they can't hover), then you're better off detecting features (eg. does it support touch events?) and adjusting accordingly.  Mobile device resolutions are getting bigger and bigger:  width is no longer an accurate way to detect them.

Comment: i need to change html according to width. i cant do that with media queries alone.

Comment: unfortunatly not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **[mobile detect JS library](http://code.google.com/p/mobileesp/source/browse/#svn/JavaScript)** to do this. Take note of the warning:

```
// WARNING: 
//   These JavaScript-based device detection features may ONLY work 
//   for the newest generation of smartphones, such as the iPhone, 
//   Android and Palm WebOS devices.
//   These device detection features may NOT work for older smartphones 
//   which had poor support for JavaScript, including 
//   older BlackBerry, PalmOS, and Windows Mobile devices. 
//   Additionally, because JavaScript support is extremely poor among 
//   'feature phones', these features may not work at all on such devices.
//   For better results, consider using a server-based version of this code, 
//   such as Java, APS.NET, PHP, or Ruby.
```

Answer (score 0):

there are two options:

1- User Agent sniffing.
2-mobile detect JS library

Answer (score 0):

You just answered your own question - you either want to adopt to user's browser or their device width.

If you want to do something when width is less than WIDTH_CONSTANT you use mediaQueries, or check dimensions with javascript.

Nowadays user agent sniffing is not advised on client side, because rather than sniffing user agent you need to look for the features that you are interested in.

So in your case I am almost confident to say that you should look for device width.

P.S. if you are dealing on server side I think that useragent sniffing would be the only way to find out about device user is using.

Comment: i want to run js code on certain browser width or device widths that is all. Basically if media query kicks in i want js to do something.